# How can I get a search term with a space to be one search term

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an elasticsearch index, with a field called "name" with a mapping as follows:

```
"name": {
   "type": "string",
   "fields": {
      "raw": {
      "type": "string",
      "index": "not_analyzed"
   }
  }
},
```

Now let's say I have a record "Brooklyn Technical High School".

I would like somebody searching for "brooklyn t*" to have that show up. For example: `http://myserver/_search?q=name:brooklyn+t*`

It seems however to be tokening the search term, and searching for  both "brooklyn" and "t", because I get back results like: "Ps 335 Granville T Woods".

I would like it to search the not_analyzed term using the whole term. Enclosing it in quotes doesn't seem to help either.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [term query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html) - 
Term query wont analyzer/tokenize the string before it apply the search.

```
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "user": "kimchy"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried that...`"name": "brooklyn t"` gives me back no results.